# frontier exploration theory and usage

Tags: ros, frontier-exploration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to understand how I can use the package frontier_exploration in order to use it for my project. I have studied the paper describing this theory by Yamauchi (1997). I would like to know whether this implementation of frontier exploration is based on the most basic theory (i.e. the greedy approach where the robot chooses its closest frontier) or whether some objective function is being used to decide upon the choice of the frontier to explore.

Thanks.

--EDIT:

When I tried to run the global_map.launch file and provided a polygon boundary + a start point, I got the following result:

```
[ WARN] [1425309222.899948026]: Please select an initial point for exploration inside the polygon
[ INFO] [1425309234.966230727]: Sending goal
[ INFO] [1425309235.049964691]: Using plugin "static"
[ INFO] [1425309235.207880621]: Requesting the map...
[ INFO] [1425309235.485626067]: Resizing costmap to 4000 X 4000 at 0.050000 m/pix
[ INFO] [1425309235.712224527]: Received a 4000 X 4000 map at 0.050000 m/pix
[ INFO] [1425309235.712476446]: Subscribing to updates
[ INFO] [1425309235.727304703]: Using plugin "explore_boundary"
[ INFO] [1425309235.923136494]: Using plugin "sensor"
[ INFO] [1425309235.969323279]:     Subscribed to Topics: laser
[ INFO] [1425309236.050620763]: Using plugin "inflation"
[ WARN] [1425309236.434748546]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 5.0000Hz... the loop actually took 0.2870 seconds
```

Nothing worked and the exploration was not performed. The nodes that I am running include: rosAria (robot control), sicktoolbox_wrapper (laser driver), tf node, gmapping to build the map. Do i need to run some other node to perform actionlib?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203769/frontier-exploration-theory-and-usage/) by [RND](https://answers.ros.org/users/21074/rnd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 133 on 2015-02-25

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Currently, only the greedy approach is used. I am interested in moving to a plugin-based architecture to allow users to write their own cost function, but this is not currently implemented.

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2015-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RND](https://answers.ros.org/users/21074/rnd/) on 2015-03-02**:
Ok thanks. I m trying to run the package through the launch file global_map.launch. I am running a Pioneer robot with rosAria and sicktoolbox_wrapper. I am using the gmapping node to build the map. Do I need to run anything else apart from these nodes in order for frontier_exploration to work?

**Comment by [RND](https://answers.ros.org/users/21074/rnd/) on 2015-03-02**:
I did not quite understand what needs to be done in Step 2: Submit a goal to the server with your own node via an actionlib SimpleActionClient. I am just running the frontier_exploration package but nothing happens when I select the starting position of the robot within the polygon boundary.

**Comment by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on 2015-03-02**:
You can find end-to-end demo usage here https://github.com/husky/husky_navigation/blob/indigo-devel/launch/exploration_demo.launch

**Comment by [RND](https://answers.ros.org/users/21074/rnd/) on 2015-03-09**:
Does move_base package work on pioneer robots? i.e. any robot that works with the ROSARIA package for robot control? because my robot moves forward by publishing on the /RosAria/cmd_vel command and does not move when using move_base.

**Comment by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on 2015-03-09**:
the navigation stack will work, but is going to require some configuration on your part. It's a whole separate can of worms http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials